# How can I reference a column name of a data frame which is in a different function from the one I want to access it from when using “mutate”?

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I am trying to access a column named "Updated_on"  which is in a data frame that can be accessed through a reactive function that is assigned a variable name dhh.

I am trying to access it from another mutate().

> Error: object 'UPDATED_on' not found.

```
   mk <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$file)) return(NULL)
    inFile <- input$file
    datatable <- read.csv(input$file[[2, 'datapath']], check.names=FALSE)
    colnames(datatable)[5] <- "Updated_on"
    return(datatable) 
  })


  output$contents <- renderDataTable({
    if (is.null(mk)) return(NULL)
    datatable <- data.frame(mk())
    datatable
  })



 output$marvin <- renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(mk()) & is.null(dhh())){return()}
    jp <- data.frame(mk())
    mu <- data.frame(dhh())
    x1=jp[order(nrow(jp):1),]

    ppp <- as.character(jp$Client.Code) 

    vcv <- c(ppp)


    tttt <- as.vector(mu$CLIENTID)


    r <- mu[mu$CLIENTID %in% vcv, ]

#this is the mutate function   
    pipo <- r %>% 
      mutate(UPDATED_on = as.Date(UPDATED_on, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))%>% 
      group_by(CLIENTID) %>%  
      arrange(desc(UPDATED_on)) %>%
      slice(1)
    pipo
```

Comment: you can access it with `dhh()$UPDATED_on` but it must be length 1 or have length == `nrow(r)`. But you should instead be using some type of `*_join()` from `dplyr` so that each value of UPDATED_on matches to the correct record in r

Comment: Thanks, let me try that out and see